about a graph theory problem

Let $G$ be a graph with $δ(G)^* ≥ k$, where $k$ is a positive integer. Show that:
$G$ contains a cycle $C_p$,where $p≥k+1$.

could someone give me a hint in order to solve this question ?
Initially I considered to a pair of vertices $u,v$ for which exists a $u-v$ path of length $k$ (which I know exists as established by an earlier exercise).my plan was to remove the points that lives in the path (except $u,v$) and lastly show that $u$ and $v$ are in the same connected component;However, I soon discovered a counterexample to this approach
$*$ this symbol represents the minimum degree of the graph

Can you edit your question to include the definition of delta?

@Wei of course.

Explaining symbols in footnotes is not very readable. I suggest you write it as "Let $G$ be a graph with $\delta(G)\geq k$, where $k$ is a positive integer and $\delta(G)$ denotes the minimum degree of $G$".

I think you need to assume that $k\gt1$.

@user14111
no, because If $\delta(G)=1$(and if the order of my graph is even)then I would have $\frac{n}{2}$ connected components each of which is $C_2$

If $G=K_2$ then $\delta(G)=1$ and there are no cycles. $\delta(C_2)=2$.

@user14111
sure, thank you

I assume that $G$ is finite and $k\gt1$.
Pick a vertex to start from and start walking along the edges, following the rule: never go to one of the last $k-1$ vertices that you've visited; this is possible since $\delta(G)=k$. Since the graph is finite, eventually you will repeat a vertex. The cycle formed in this way will have length at least $k+1$
